# Laravel Blade - pass variable via an @include or @yield

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to pass a variable to an included Blade file. I have attempted this two-ways; however, neither have been successful.

1. Pass a variable, `title`, to the included file:

   ```
   @section('left')
       @include('modal', ['title' => 'Hello'])
   @stop
   ```
2. Use `@yield` and set the section:

   ```
   @section('left')
       @include('modal')
           @section('title')
           Hello
           @stop
   @stop
   ```

I am using Laravel 4.2. I am unaware if what I am trying to do is possible, but I imagine it is.

Comment: How are you trying to output it? The first option is definitely valid.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like `[]` brackets. Using `array('title' => 'hello')` works, though.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Shorthand arrays were introduced in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#blade-templating), the `include`-way should be the way to do it:

> **Including Sub-Views**
>
> `@include('view.name')`
>
> You may also pass an array of data to the included view:
>
> `@include('view.name', array('some'=>'data'))`

My hunch is that `$title` is conflicting with another variable in your nested templates. Just for troubleshooting, try temporarily calling it something else.

Comment: This works, for some reason it didn't like the `[]` brackets, though. How does the `yield` way work - if it is the correct way?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Meant `include`. As for the short array syntax, maybe your php version doesn't support the short array syntax. Which version are you using?

Comment: Yes - you're correct! Thanks. Is this the *preferred* Laravel way of doing things? I.e., lots of includes and passing variable to re-use a template?

Comment: That pretty much depends on your use case. For code that's supposed to be repeated, and which by nature is a _sub_-component and not included in every single view (fx. a modal, page-specific navigation etc.), I'd definitely use subviews.

Comment: Ok, sure! I need to pass an `@include(...)` as a variable (to populate the item I am including). Is this possible? All that seems to occurs is it prints out '@include(...)'

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you need to nest it like that, try `['someVar' => view('my.view')]`. I'd prefer doing something like `@include('viewA', ['subview' => 'viewB'])` and inside `viewA.blade.php`, use `@include($subview)`. Just spitballing though.

Comment: Spot on. However, Why does it not need quotes? Doing what I had been doing: `@include('{{$subview}}')` doesn't work.

Comment: I believe that the `@include` expression is evaluated before the rest of the blade syntax, and therefore, whats inside the parenthesis must be pure PHP. `'{{$subview}}'` in pure PHP is just a string consisting of a couple of curly brackets, a dollar-sign and so on, whereas `"{$subview}"` (note the double-quotes) or simply `$subview` would work as you expect (see `include` as a simple function) because they're interpreted as normal PHP.

Answer (score 7):

pass an array of data to the included view

```
@include('view.name', array('some'=>'data'))
```

then use this on view/name folder

```
{{ $some }}
```