# Laravel Blade Passing Variables to Other Blades

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried a few things to try to get this to work. I was looking at this --
[Laravel Blade - pass variable via an @include or @yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938362/laravel-blade-pass-variable-via-an-include-or-yield) -- question about how to pass variables between blades but I can't seem to get it to work!

I have a view calling my header view (in /resources/views/layouts/frontendbasic.blade.php):

```
@include('common/head', array('url'=>'www.url.com'))
```

And in the header blade (in /resources/views/common/head.blade.php) I am calling that variable like this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ $url }}" />
```

And I get the error:

```
Undefined variable: url
(View: ...\resources\views\common\head.blade.php) 
(View: ...\resources\views\common\head.blade.php) 
(View: ...\resources\views\common\head.blade.php)
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem, creating some test pages and passing through the variable exactly like you did, and it works for me. What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct thing is to pass a variable through the controller:

```
return view('view.path', [
     'url' => 'www.url.com'
]);
```

however, try as below:

```
@include('common.head', ['url' => 'www.url.com'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I swear I tried with the brackets too! But I guess maybe I had some lame type. Thank you so much! This is working

Comment: @TurtleBo The brackets work? Or you do it across controller?

Comment: I used brackets. But I've ran across more issues so I'll probably try to do it across the controller. I really appreciate it!

Comment: `@include` uses a dot syntax, not slash.

Answer (score 2):

there are many way to done this. you can also use "compact" and "with" function for pass variable into blade in controller and blade also.

in controller

```
  $info = 23; /* variable you want to pass into blade */ 

  return view('view.path',compact('info'));
  OR
  return view('view.path')->with('info'=>$info);
```

in view

```
 @include('view.path',compact('variable_name'));
 OR
 @include('view.path')->with('key' => $value);
```