# How to pull database table values into a template file?

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

How can I pull database values into a template? (`footer.blade.php`). I can pull data into `home.blade.php` just fine but since I'm just doing `@include('templates.footer')`, I'm not sure how to pull table values into `footer.blade.php`

This is my current setup:

**HomeController.php**

```
public function index() {

$general = DB::table('general')->get();

return view('home', ['general' => $general]);

}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('templates.master')

@section('content')
    @foreach($general as $key => $data)
        {{ $data -> content}}
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>
    @include('templates.header')

    @yield('content')

    @include('templates.footer')
</body>
```

**footer.blade.php**

```
<footer class="footer padding-medium">
This is the footer
</footer>
```

I am looking to do something like this:

**footer.blade.php**

```
<footer class="footer padding-medium">
    @foreach($general as $key => $data)
        {{ $data -> content}}
    @endforeach
</footer>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Blade - pass variable via an @include or @yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938362/laravel-blade-pass-variable-via-an-include-or-yield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AppServiceProvider.php which is located in app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php using View composer.

Like

```
View::composer('templates.footer',function($view){
  $view->with('results', DB::table('general')->get());
});
```

In footer

```
<footer class="footer padding-medium">
@foreach($results as $key => $data)
    {{ $data -> content}}
@endforeach
 </footer>
```

Do not forget import DB & View in the AppServiceProvider.php file